# Best way to limit/throttle users on API Gateway endpoint with Cognito User Pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have set up a few endpoints using Lambda functions, API Gateway and an AWS Cognito user pool. I currently only have Congito setup as the Authorizer, I do not generate API keys for individual users (should I?). Now I want to throttle users so that they cannot concurrently call the API. Eg, one user should only be able to send one request at a time, but multiple users should be able to use it concurrently.

Is there a way to do this through Usage Plans?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes for your question